# How to create different layout compatible for Android Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing application for Android3.0 which must be compatible for all tablet size. When i googled for my problem i got a solution as in below link

[Multiple Screen Resoultion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633792/android-app-support-for-multiple-tablet-screen-resolutions)

When i am trying this, i got another problem as showing error as   "**w600dp, Portrait Orientation' is not a best match for any device/locale combination**"

For this problem i have googled and got the final solution as in following link as [Eclipse spits out a cryptic error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774686/android-xml-layouts-eclipse-spits-out-a-cryptic-error-message).  What ever i have tried i didnt solve my problem

Can anyone please give me solution.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: "When i am trying this, i got another problem as showing error as "w600dp, Portrait Orientation' is not a best match for any device/locale combination"" -- this is simply a warning from the Eclipse GUI editor and has no bearing on your actual application.

Comment: @CommonsWare this may be warning from Eclipse but when i alter in layout which is in layout-sw600-port it also reflect in the default layout as layout-port as given in the second link of my question. please give me solution for this. Its very urgent..